# What is the difference between these two ways of initializing a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the difference between the two :

```
hashMap_2 = hashMap_1;
```

and

```
hashMap_2 = new HashMap<Object_1,Object_2>(hashMap_1);
```

Is there any difference between the two ?

Accoriding to me both initializes a new `HashMap` named `hashMap_2`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- The statement `hashMap_2 = hashMap_1;` means that **both variables
  refer to same object**.
- The variable `hashMap_2` will now refer to the object being referred by `hashMap_1`.
- This means only one object will be there but two variables referring to same object.
- The statement `hashMap_2 = new HashMap<Object_1,Object_2>(hashMap_1);` **causes  another hashmap to be
  created** with the values of `hashMap_1`.
- There will be two different `HashMap` objects and they will have same values

Answer (score 4):

First expression doesn't initialize a HashMap. Its just assigning the reference.

Answer (score 1):

### ASSIGNMENT

This statement `hashMap_2 = hashMap_1;` is called ***reference assignment***, where same object is referred by two reference variables.

### INITIALIZING

When initializing a `Object` then it comes with a `new` operator, except primitives. Initialization process creates a new object on heap, whereas assignment does not create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.hashMap_2 = hashMap_1;
```

hashMap_1 values has been assigned to hashMap_2

```
2.hashMap_2 = new HashMap<Object_1,Object_2>(hashMap_1);
```

new HashMap object(hashMap_2) was created

The differnce for both experssion is **Assignment and Intialization**

Answer (score 0):

As every one said

hashMap_2 = hashMap_1; -->asssigns reference of HashMap1 to hashMap_2

and

hashMap_2 = new HashMap(hashMap_1);   -->causes another hashmap to be created.

Adding below point

In both the cases the Object stored in the hashmap2 and  hashMap_1 will be the same. Both will not do deep clonning